# Variables (fields?) Won't Display in Django Generic Detail View

Tags: python, django, detailsview

I have been loosely following a tutorial and can't seam to get a generic detail view to work properly. I am calling with a pk and the page displays but the variable {{publisher.name}} doesn't show up.  I have deleted some of the code from views and the model which I consider peripheral but if there error isnt obvious I can repost.

All files are in the poll directory except the HTML file is in poll/template/poll

Thanks

The URL.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from poll.views import PublisherList
from . import views

app_name = "poll"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^publishers/$', PublisherList.as_view(), name = "publisherlist"),
    url(r'^start/', views.PublisherCreate.as_view(), name = 'make-publisher'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PublisherDetail.as_view(), name = 'detail-publisher'),
]
```

The View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import ListView
from poll.models import Publisher

...

class PublisherDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Publisher
    template_name = 'Poll/publisher_details.html'
```

and the HTML file

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{{ Publisher.name }}</h1>
<h1>Options</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

and the models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your models here.


class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-name"]

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('build:details', kwargs = {'pk':self.pk})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object in the template is called `publisher`, not `Publisher`.

Comment: Well, usually it's `object`.

Comment: No, `get_context_object_name()` uses the lower-cased name of the model.

Comment: Both works: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data

Comment: I swear I had tried both ways, but that did it.  Thanks for the Help everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the instance of the model like this in the template. `Publisher` is the name of your Model class but not an instance of it. The default name of the object in a generic detail view is `object`. So you need to use `{{ object.name }}`. Or you can use the lowercased Model name too as a default. In your case thats `publisher`.

If you want to change the variable name of your object you have to implement `get_context_object_name(obj)` method of your detail view.
The method has to return a string with the desired variable name of the object in your detail view template.

Answer (score 0):

The default name of the object in the template is `object`, while the lowercase model name serves as an alias (`publisher`). You can specify that name in the view via the class attribute `context_object_name`, as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects):

```
class PublisherDetail(generic.DetailView):
    # ...
    context_object_name = 'foo'
```

Then

```
{{ foo.name }}
# {{ publisher.name }}  should work out of the box
```

will work in the template.

Comment: It will work out of the box with `publisher` because the lowercased model name is a default alias to `object`. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name).